# Cluster Lock Manager without TCP/IP

Tags: linux, filesystems, security, file-sharing, cluster

I have 2 linux sharing same SAN disk LUN. There are many cluster files systems to manage lock/unlock. But all of them are using a seperate TCP/IP comminication.

But I need a cluster lock manager which is using only this shared SAN LUN. Because of security there is no any TCP/IP network between two linux server.

Only simple file sharing is required. One node will write a new file, then other node will read that file and delete it.

Comment: What are the security concerns? Is there not a way to either give them a private switch or connect via crossover cables?

Comment: Only Fiber Channel SAN connection is permitted. Dont think this as a normal cluster. Only simple file sharing is required. One node will write a file, other node will read and delete that file.

Comment: You didn't specify the security concerns, you just repeated that the SAN was all that you could use. If the switch only communciates with other nodes in the cluster then there's no new exposure.

Comment: There must be airgap between two linux server because of the TEMPEST security. Only FC SAN connection is permitted.

Answer (score 0):

Redhat cluster use a fencing method called **fence scsi**.

The fencing node forbid the other from accessing lun in SAN.

however, this still requires some sort of TCP/IP communication between node.

I assume that by

> Because of security there is no any TCP/IP network between two linux
>   server.

you meant nodes can't access ILO/iDrac feature to power off the other node.

One major purpose of cluster is having services/packages switching from one node to anoter carrying a valid TCP/IP address, thus you must have TCP/IP connectivity.

Comment: On the last part of your answer, this could be an HPC and not necessarily an HA cluster. Those typically have TCP/IP connectivity for receiving work and submitting results, though. Either way you're right in that a cluster is going to need TCP/IP and it sounds like the OP received a security requirement from someone unfamiliar with the technology.